# hibernate-search MassIndexer ERROR

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I would like to reindex entities in elasticsearch index with `MassIndexer` system from hibernate-search-orm project.

It could be great ;) but it tells me some exceptions.

However as you can see below, example is basic:

1. the entity:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "STUDENT")
   @Indexed
   @ProvidedId (bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = StudentFieldBridge.class))
   public class StudentEntity {

       @EmbeddedId
       private RegistrationId regid;

       @Field
       private String name;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. the `registrationId`:

   ```
   @Embeddable
   public class RegistrationId implements Serializable{

       @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
       private int studentId;

       @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT")
       private String department;
       ...
   }
   ```
3. the student field bridge:

   ```
   public class StudentFieldBridge implements TwoWayStringBridge {

       @Override
       public Object stringToObject(String stringValue) {
           String[] split = stringValue.split("_");
           RegistrationId ret = new RegistrationId();
           ret.setDepartment(split[0]);
           ret.setStudentId(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
           return ret;
       }

       @Override
       public String objectToString(Object object) {
           RegistrationId id = (RegistrationId) object;
           return id.getDepartment() + "_" + id.getStudentId();
       }
   }
   ```
4. the mass indexation

   ```
   @Test
   public void massIndexation() throws InterruptedException {
       EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("studentPu").createEntityManager();
       org.hibernate.Session hibernateSession = (Session)em.getDelegate();
       FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(hibernateSession);
       fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
   }
   ```
5. and finally the error :

   ```
   ERROR: HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000212: An exception occurred while the MassIndexer was transforming identifiers to Lucene Documents
   java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getEntityName(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:626)
   at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:509)
   at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.findColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:525)
   at org.hibernate.criterion.InExpression.toSqlString(InExpression.java:43)
   at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:400)
   at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:106)
   at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:75)
   at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:80)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1760)
   at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
   at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:175)
   at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadAllFromQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:140)
   at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:117)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
   ```

java project dependencies are :

```
testCompile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.0.8.Final'
testCompile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-search-orm', version: '5.6.0.Alpha3'
testCompile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch', version: '5.6.0.Alpha3'
```

Thanks to project team for your job !

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
@Indexed
public class StudentEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    @DocumentId
    @FieldBridge(impl = StudentFieldBridge.class)
    private RegistrationId regid;

    @Field
    private String name;
```

The problem is caused by the `@ProvidedId` annotation, which is not compatible with the `MassIndexer`: it is meant for other frameworks which integrate with Hibernate Search to directly provide ids which are assigned externally.
If the id is assigned externally, the MassIndexer can not guess them so these should not be used together.

I'll try to clarify the documentation for `ProvidedId` about this, or possibly deprecate / remove the annotation as I didn't expect it to cause such a confusing error. Thanks for reporting!